# How to get stringValue from NSTableView item

Tags: nstableview

I have NSTableView widh datas.
I want loop on every row and I want get cell values

I do so :

```
NSTableColumn *col_1;
col_1 = [myTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"gen"];

NSMutableString *col_1_value = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
col_1_value = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[col_1 dataCellForRow:0] stringValue]];
```

but I get for first run Text Cell and then for second run I get right value,
where is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Implement following delegate method, you can directly access cell value

```
  - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSLog(@"cell value is %@",[cell stringValue]);
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: But I get cell value when user click on button, how can I do ?

Comment: when you click on button what should happen to table view, means it should select first row of that table or anything else like this?